# Throwing FileNotFoundException but not catching

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

I am getting a FileNotFoundException while trying to execute a function with a try-catch block. I've tried catching a FileNotFoundException, to no avail. Can anyone tell me why it does this?

```
public static bool IsKeyValid(string path)
{
    bool rVal = false;

    try
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(path + "\\data.bin", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        ValidKey vk = (ValidKey)bf.Deserialize(stream);
        if (vk.SerialNumber != null)
            rVal = true;
        else
            rVal = false;

    }
    catch (Exception fnfe)
    {
            rVal = false;
    }
    return rVal;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered checking if the file actually exists?

Comment: What are you passing in the path variable?

Comment: First: Double check your path variable. Second: Use Path.Combine method.

Comment: Yes. It's not supposed to exist until it's created by another function when this one returns false. And Path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: Also use `File.Exists()` first - catching exceptions is incredibly expensive.

Comment: Your function already returns `bool`, so you could just return true, false, or FieNotFound  :)

Comment: Actually, just using the File.Exists() method fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's breaking into the `FileNotFoundException` in the debugger when it's initially thrown, but that it would be correctly caught by the catch block. You can change the debugger settings for exceptions - or just run it outside the debugger, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The catch you have will catch all exceptions, but depending on how you have Visual Studio configured, it might still stop on the line raising the exception to give you a chance at debugging before the handler kicks in.

Go to the `Debug|Exceptions` menu to control this.