# Cannot catch FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, .net-4.5

I think I am having a similar issue as already asked in [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423464/throwing-filenotfoundexception-but-not-catching). When I run the following code in my current project, I receive a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, although I actually catch it.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

public LoadFile(string xmlFile)
{
    try {xmlDocument.Load(xmlFile);}
    catch {xmlDocument.LoadXml("<settings></settings>");} // File does not exist
}
```

However, when I create a new project with this piece of code, the Exception is catched correctly.

I cannot see any difference between my current project and the new project (same .NET version, both 32bit).

In the other thread, *Jon Skeet* gives the following answer to this question:

> My guess is that it's breaking into the FileNotFoundException in the debugger when it's initially thrown, but that it would be correctly caught by the catch block. You can change the debugger settings for exceptions - or just run it outside the debugger, of course.

I do not understand it. I do not want to disable `FileNotFoundException`. Can anyone further explain this, please?

EDIT: I know that I could use `File.Exists(...)` instead; however, I am still wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: Jon isn't talking about "disabling exception". There are two ways to let the debugger handle exceptions: 1.) break immediately when the exception is thrown, or 2.) break when the exception isn't handled by a catch block. If you have 1.) enabled then the debugger will break although the catch block would handle the exception later.

Comment: OK. So, I just enabled `Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General -> Enable Just My Code`. However, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Again, when use this piece of code in a new project, the Exception gets catched correctly. I run both projects in Debug mode. This still does not make any sense to me.

Comment: wrong options: Debugger -> Exceptions... -> Reset All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code under debugger control, the debugger will **always** intercept exceptions before your catch block. The question is whether or not the debugger displays a message, and that depends on debugger settings. If the debugger handles an exception by displaying a message, it's then up to you If you want to continue execution (which would pass control to your catch block) or not (terminating your application). It depends on how you respond to the dialog. If you turn off "thrown" exceptions in the debugger, you will still see evidence that the debugger is intercepting them (they will be logged in the Output window), but there will be no interruption in flow of control to your catch block.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation! When I run [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15530/Quick-and-Dirty-Settings-Persistence-with-XML), the debugger does not intercept, although I am running it in Debug Mode. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: I just noticed that [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15530/Quick-and-Dirty-Settings-Persistence-with-XML) has a different setting in `Debug -> Exceptions`. My current project does not have a column named `User-unhandled`. I guess, that's my problem.

Comment: Problem Solved now. You were right, of course. I still had another problem: I used numbers in my xPath, which seems to be not allowed. That raisd an unhandled Exception.

Answer (score 0):

He is saying that the debugger is catching(intercepting) the error and showing you something onscreen, instead of allowing the actual catch mechanism to throw the error.

That is why they say to deactivate it if you want to see how the code will perform in actual use.  Deactive it, run the code, see the exception being caught and reactivate it.

You might want to check the settings when the other project is loaded.  It might have a stored configuration saying to deactivate the debugger intercepting the FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Or just press F5 to let the control flow to the exception handler.

Comment: OK, but when I create a new project and copy this piece of code into that new project, the debugger does not intercept anything. Why is that?

Comment: @berti It will depend on two things: whether or not you are running the code under debugger control, and(if running under the debugger) whether or not debug settings are set to intercept exceptions.